# Why does strtok() append a space to the last token

Tags: c, fgets, strtok, minix, string.h

I am working on creating a simple version of Minix. I am using `fgets()` to grab user input. I am then using `strtok()` to split the string up with the delimiter `" "`. The problem is when I call `strtok(NULL, " ")`, my token stored appends a space to the last char. So if I pass `"minimount imagefile.img"`, my program will grab `minimount` and store it in variable `cmd`, then it will grab `"imagefile.img "` and place it in variable `flag`. Notice the space at the end of the `flag` variable is added after the token method.

Is there a way for me to grab just the string without a space at the end after token is called. Or is there a way to manipulate the string to remove the appended space?

```
printf("Minix: ");

fgets(cmd, BUFFLIM, stdin);

//parses string using delimiter " "

char *token = strtok(cmd, " ");

//assigns flag to what is after delimiter 

char *f = strtok(NULL, " ");

//printf("cmd:%s\nf:%s\n", cmd, f);

printf("cmd:%s\nf:%s", cmd, f);
```

Output:

```
cmd:"minimount"
f:"imagefile.img "
```

Comment: It is probably not really a space, but the newline, which `fgets()` adds to the buffer. You have to remove this newline manually.

Comment: This looks like it may be a bug. [`strtok()` is supposed to terminate that second token](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.8p4). Please provide a *complete* example

Comment: Your quoted output with `"` around the `flag` variable doesn't match the code — which has `f` instead of `flag` and doesn't print any double quotes.  That leaves us wondering what goes with what — you need to make sure your code matches your question.

Answer (score 4):

The standard function `fgets` can append the new line character `'\n'` to the entered string provided that there is enough space in the corresponding character array.

So use

```
char *f = strtok(NULL, " \n");
```

instead of

```
char *f = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

From the C Standard (7.21.7.2 The fgets function)

> 2 The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of
>   characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into
>   the array pointed to by s. **No additional characters are read after a
>   new-line character (which is retained)** or after end-of-file. A null
>   character is written immediately after the last character read into
>   the array.

Another approach is initially to remove the character from the entered string as for example

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//...

fgets(cmd, BUFFLIM, stdin);
cmd[ strcspn( cmd, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

As for your code snippet then it seems you have the following result as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[100];

    fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin );

    char *cmd = strtok( s, " " );

    char *f = strtok( NULL, " " );

    printf( "cmd:\"%s\"\nf:\"%s\"", cmd, f );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
cmd:"minimount"
f:"imagefile.img
"
```

Comment: Thank you for solving the problem. Issue was fgets() appends the newline char so using cmd[ strcspn( cmd, "\n" ) ] = '\0'; worked!